# Initializing an object in a context in Python

Tags: python, initialization

this looks like a trivial problem, but I would be really grateful for some help. Maybe it will help other people too with understanding of initializing.

I'm implementing something that, in some context, will get market data for the given time period, calculate returns, and then, later, when this piece of code will be working, will calculate optimal weights in a portfolio.

For now, I'm having problems with this stage:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime

class Black_Litterman:

    def initialize(context):

        context.start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        context.end = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 28)

        # Select five large cap equities for the portfolio
        # Apple, Google, GE, Microsoft, Amazon
        # later, these should be read in from a csv file stored elsewhere
        context.securities = ['AAPL', 'GOOGL', 'GE', 'MSFT', 'AMZN']
        context.market_cap = [479.51, 377.58, 272.76, 300.86, 180.96]
        context.cap_wts = np.array(context.market_cap)/sum(np.array(context.market_cap))

        # Set Max and Min positions in security
        context.max_notional = 1000000.1
        context.min_notional = -1000000.0

    def get_data(context, data):

        all_prices = []
        cont_start_str = (context.start).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        cont_end_str = (context.end).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        for i in context.securities:
            f = web.DataReader(i, 'google', context.start, context.end)
            all_prices.append(f.ix[cont_start_str : cont_end_str, 'Open'])

        # Drop missing values and transpose matrix
        daily_returns = all_prices.pct_change().dropna().values.T
```

When I try

```
cont = Black_Litterman()
Black_Litterman.get_data(cont, 0)
```

I get

```
AttributeError: Black_Litterman instance has no attribute 'start'
```

which means that even if cont is an instance of this class, it wasn't initialized with the initial parameters.
Would there be a way to initialize it (different from the traditional (**init**( self, start, end, ...)) )?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You didn't create an attribute start for Black_Litterman so it doesn't know context.start should exist. Your class really doesn't make sense in general.

Comment: Hi Dylan, in the initializing part, I did create that attribute:                    context.start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)    but apparently, it wasn't really used. Do you know what should have been done to use this initialization function? Thank you!

Comment: If you mean in `initialize(context)` then no. You're assigning start, but `context.start` doesn't exist for `context` which is a `Black_Litterman` type. Do you have a `__init__()` defined for this class?

Comment: As an aside, from the python style guide [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): _"Always use self for the first argument to instance methods."_ it is considered bad form to use `"context"` for the `self` reference if you plan to share this code with anybody.

Comment: Thank you, @tdelaney ! Actually, that was my main concern. I managed to make the code work, but I also wanted to learn some good programming practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion! I got it now. All I needed to do was to call

```
cont = Black_Litterman()

cont.initialize()
```

and only then

```
Black_Litterman.get_data(cont, 0)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I cant actually understand, what are you trying to do, but i python to  initialize instance of class with default parameters, you should do something like this:

```
class Black_Litterman:

    def __init__(self):

        self.start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        self.end = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 28)
        ....

    def get_data(self, data):

        all_prices = []
        cont_start_str = self.start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        cont_end_str = self.end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        ...
# Use it like this
bl_instance = Black_Litterman()
bl_instance.get_data(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, aleosd! I figured out a solution that was more convenient in my context, but this would also work.